# How to handle concurrent updates for the same record in a distributed system

Tags: concurrency, message-queue, go, locks, scaling

I'm trying to figure out the best solution for the below. Any help would be great.

So basically I have a service (that can be scaled horizontally), which listens on a queue. Every message received will be dispatched into a job and processed concurrently.

The job will (in same order):

1. Generate some data based on the message payload
2. Cache the data on Redis
3. Send the data to another service

My issue is when another message is received for the same logical record (same table record but with altered data).
I need to make sure that the latest version of the data is cached on Redis and sent to the next service in the scenario where 2 or more messages with the same record id are being processed. Hence avoiding that a job with an old version of the payload is overwriting the latest one.

I thinking about using some distributed locking mechanism, not sure if that's efficient, especially when I want the latest version to be sent to the next service quickly as possible.
Maybe someway to cancel a job for an outdated payload instead of locking the whole job? Using Redis pubsub to communicate between the service (When scaling) or have a better way?

Comment: What makes a record the "old version" versus the "latest one"?  Creation time?  Submission time?  Something else?

Comment: @JimmyJames The updated time

Comment: OK perfect but what determines that?  There are many times you could use: when you read it off of the queue to process it, when it was placed on a queue, when it was created in before being put on the queue (this could have any number of times to choose from)

Comment: @JimmyJames, when a record is updated, it is pushed on a queue for the service to pickup and process it

Comment: Right.  But I'm still not sure what "updated time" means to you.  Is it the time that the message was put on the queue?  How are you defining that?  Are you recording that time as part of the request?

Comment: "update time" is the time the record was updated. the record is push on a queue then.

Comment: `....avoiding that a job with an old version of the payload is overwriting the latest one....` Why not keep all versions with  version number and use the latest one ?

Comment: Are you recording that update time on the message that you put on the queue?

Comment: Yeah, each time a record is updated, it's updated_at field is updated. It's being saved in a DB and then push on a queue for the service in question to process. More details in the comment section of @Ewan's answer.

Comment: @Alan So if you have two records with timestamps on them, it seems rather straightforward to determine which one is newer.  It's not clear what exactly what issue you are struggling with.

Comment: @JimmyJames, we are in a distributed env where the service can be scaled, and jobs are being run concurrently, and i want to make sure that the latest data is being pushed to the final service asap and discard job for old payload if there is, and also avoid that a job with old payload (process slower) overwrite a newly cached data (since they are reused). Might make user of Version and Distributed locking (before caching)

Comment: I'm sure it's not as simple as this but based on what you've stated so far checking that that timestamp of the message you are processing is not before the timestamp of the current version in the DB should suffice.  In order to come up with a really robust solution, it's important to completely define the problem you are trying to solve.  I think you might be trying to skip that part of the process.  My intention with these questions is to help you get to that point.

Comment: @JimmyJames yeah i know you're helping and thks for that. Yeah will check the timestamp but will need to have some distributed locking since 2 process could be reading it at the same time.

Comment: @Alan You keep mentioning the 'same time'. Not to get too philosophical on you, but Einstein showed that there is no such thing in general. I know it sounds silly but these ideas were formulated in part because he was evaluating patents on clock synchronization systems for railroads which isn't that different from the kind of issue you are working on here. Anyway, you say you need to avoid sending an old request overwriting a new request and then mention they could happen at the same time. If they are 'at the same time' there is no new or old. So you need to figure out what that means to you.

Comment: @JimmyJames, by that i meant they got processed at the same time even though they were modified at different time (1 scenario). So i would need to check the timestamp of the previous cached data on redis. if current request data is older, i discard the request. But still i would have to make use of distributed locking for that

Comment: @Alan Another answer that simplifies things is to put everything in the database with the date i.e. you use versioned records.  The loading an old record will never overwrite a new one.  When you retrieve the data, you pull the newest that is available.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would create a meta record per message containing the following components:

- Key of the logical record
- Timestamp of this message
- Payload value

Let each process create its record in an interim data store, and invalidates the permanent data store. then allow a housekeeping process (call it the referee) to decide on the latest version, and promotes it to be visible in the final data store.

This setup optimizes for writes.

Of course this technique has scale-ability limitations, below a certain threshold it should reach eventual consistency.

When retrieving your data, you pull it from a priority retrieving system such that:

- If permanent data store is not invalidated, select it
- If data store is invalidated, select data from your temporary data store, sorted by timestamp descending

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if im wrong but it sounds like you have the following data flow

```
Message Queue: InBox
Service1 : read message from InBox
           process InBox.Id
           save result to Redis
           send message to S1Out with S1Out.Id = Start.Id

Message Queue: S1Out
Service2 : read message from S1Out
           read data from Redis with S1Out.Id
           save data to DB
```

The problem being that you can get 2 InBox messages for the same Id and the redis data will be overwritten by the second request processed. Causing Service 2 to behave oddly.

Really I would like to send all the data required by Service 2 in the S1Out Message rather than have S2 lookup the data in the redis cache. (Big Messages)

This eliminates the problem and a central point of failure/bottleneck of the cache.

However. An alternate approach would be to generate a new Id for each item saved in the cache and to add that Id to the message. This allows Service 2 to pick up the correct data for the job.

The second problem of having a redundant job flowing through the queue is harder to deal with until you hit a shared resource.

In my example Service 2 saves the data to a DB. At this point it is able to check to see if its job was redundant. It knows the timestamp from the original message and the database knows the timestamp of processed messages, so the service can compare and skip or drop out of date work.

Alternatively, you could add an extra 'Router Worker' whose only job is to read from S1Out, keep a buffer of messages and remove or reorder redundant work and post to S1Out2. But this becomes another central point of failure; as if you have two of them they can't see each others buffer.

My preferred approach is to process all messages and to drop redundant effects only when they would cause a real issue. (ie, not just be more optimal of cpu usage)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it and reply you asap, won't be available for the next few hours.

Comment: am actually sending the generated data payload to Service 2 (not using redis). Also, the generated data is not being save in a DB. It is just being pushed to clients through websocket by Service 2. I want to prevent Service 1 from sending an outdated payload (if let say it was slow to process) to Service 2.

Comment: its the client that can check the timestamp then

Comment: what's best way to make sure Service 1 is always caching the latest record, and not having a slow process with an outdated payload overwrite the cache, or possibly 2 process running at the same time. Use Redis distributed locking when caching the data?

Comment: @Alan if you are sending the data in the payload then i don't understand where you cache fits. can you clarify your question? But i think my 'Router Worker' is the solution you want

Comment: the data 'a' received on Service 1 is used to generate data 'b', and 'b' is cached on Redis. I want to make sure that Service 1 provide data consistency and is scalable.

Comment: but what is b used by and for what?

Comment: so the actual usage is, i have a playlist(s) which contains media/sub playlist. If playlist 1 is modified, Service 1 get a message for that, it then generate a plan for playlist 1 and cache it before send it to Service 2. Now let playlist 2 has playlist 1 as sub playlist, when playlist 2 is modified, it's send to Service 1 and Service 1 will retrieve the cached version of playlist 1 and appending it to the plan for playlist 2. So that's the main use of the cache Does that make more sense?

Comment: hmm not really.

Comment: i'm basically generating a plan (media playing, etc) for a playlist, but since playlist can have nested sub playlist, i use the cached version to generate the main playlist plan instead of having to recursively generate it for sub playlists. The final plan will be kind of falttened.